# Custom controller for the layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an MVC website which I wanted to implement a globalization/localization. On my `_Layout.cshtml`, I have a dropdown which have the languages I supported. When a user selected a language on that dropdown, it should automatically post to the server then render the new language.

Is it possible that I create a specific custom controller for the `_Layout.cshtml` only? If yes, how? If no, is there any possible way or approach I can make?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should move that to a child action, then call the child action from the layout view.

You can make the form POST to a separate action (in a controller shared with the child action) that sets the cookie / session / DB property, then redirects back to the original URL (via `Request.UrlReferrer` or from a hidden model-bound field).

Comment: Can I put the child action to any controller?

Comment: @Gerald: Of course.  But since it's linked to the POST action, it's nicer to put them together.

Comment: Request.UrlReferrer it is not 100% correct way as there are many ways that URLReferrer can be blocked by security software/Antivirus, Firewall, Proxy program. URLReferrer will be null in Pop Ups.

Comment: @PKKG: Yes; that's why I gave the second option.  Here, it will be slightly more reliable, since it will always be coming as a `<form>` POST from your own page.

Comment: @SLaks - what do you mean "it's nicer to put them together"? the child action and ?

Comment: @Gerald: And the action that handles the POST to change languages.

Comment: @SLaks : How about `Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]` ?

Comment: @PKKG: That will give the current (POST) action; not the action for the original URL.  You want `@Html.Hidden("SourceUrl", Request.Url)`

Comment: @SLaks - follow up question. Is it better to use the `@Html.RenderAction` to trigger the child action or use javascript? I wanted to trigger that child action when the selection changed.

Comment: @Gerald That depends on what behavior you want.  Only use JS if you want it to first appear on user interaction.