# ChildAction triggered on dropdown change in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to trigger a `ChildAction` on the Home Controller on the `onchange` event of a dropdown. The dropdown is located at the `_Layout.cshtml`.

Is it possible to do it on javascript?

Here is my code as of the moment.

```
$('#langDropdown').change(function() {
    var lang = $(this).val();
    alert(lang);
});
```

And here is my dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Language", ViewData["Languages"] as SelectList, 
         new { id = language })
```

It not inside of any form. Any suggestion how can I do it. Thanks!

Note: I just use alert for testing purposes.

Comment: Here is a post with an example: http://blog.yojimbocorp.com/2012/09/25/asp-net-mvc-with-ajax-calls-to-controller-actions/

Comment: @DavidTansey : OP is looking for Child Action Example.

Comment: Why not use a form? (which is what I meant in my original answer)

Comment: @SLaks - How can I do that? Just include `@Html.BeginForm("ControllerName")`?

Comment: @Gerald: Exactly, but with an action name.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your dropdown in a form that submits a POST request to a separate action (this action can have the same name as the child action).

The POST action would want to redirect back to the original URL, as I explained in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18554430/34397) (see also comments).

Comment: What will trigger that form to be submitted?

Comment: #SLaks : If possible can you give a short example for **You should put your dropdown in a form that submits a POST request to a separate action (this action can have the same name as the child action).**

Comment: @PKKG: What do you mean? An example for which part? What is unclear?

Comment: I could not understand this sentence **this action can have the same name as the child action**

Comment: @PKKG: You need a separate action method for the form to POST to.  This can have the same name as the child action that I assumed was rendering the form in the first place.  The child action would be called by the layout, and the POST action would be referenced in the form.

Comment: we need a post action method for the dropdown(this is inside the form). You are suggesting another action method with ChildOnly Attribute ?

Comment: @PKKG: That depends on where you want to put the form.

Comment: Is it possible if you include you suggestion with some code(Controller/Action Method/Layout code) not briefly

Comment: @PKKG: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx The point of a child action is to use controller-side logic to render a view as part of a layout.  If you need any controller logic to create the form, put it in a child action that returns a partial view with only the form tag.

Comment: @SLaks - I tried using `@Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller")` but it returned me an error saying The action is only accessible by child request.

Comment: @Gerald: The POST action should not be a child action.

Comment: @SLaks - I am still stuck at how am I gonna call that ChildAction on onchange event of dropdown. I definitely needed to study mvc. Thanks for the info btw!

Comment: @Gerald: You don't.  Child actions are only used to render a view as part of a different view.   When changing the dropdown, you would invoke a _separate_ POST action, either by submitting the `<form>` or by AJAX.